# Data loading in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to read in data using numpy or pandas which has been previously aperture by some camera software. The nominal matrix is 160 x 160 pixels with the aperture switched off but when the auto aperture is on I am losing most of my data during import. I am assuming because I am not handling the whitespace or NaN's appropriately. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle the data with the auto aperture ON?

[image]

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

try:
    my_data2 = genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter=',')

except:
    
    my_data2 = genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter='    ')
```

Comment: I'd suggest you open the file in a [text editor](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-most-popular-technologies-integrated-development-environment), preferably one which can render whitespace markers, to inspect whether the file is space, tab, fixed width, or some other format.

Comment: `genfromtxt` can handle missing fields when the delimiter is something like a comma, but the if the "delimiter" is white-space (the default), one blank is the same as a dozen.  And excel display isn't going help us help you.  A sample of the actual csv text file might.